# android & testing with Robotium, how select a element of the listView in fragment?

Tags: android, listview, testing, fragment, robotium

In testing with Robotium, how select a element of the listView in fragment ?
I have  2 fragment Container in layout :

```
>     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>      ... 
>         <FrameLayout
>             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:id="@+id/fragment_container_left"
>         ... />
>         <FrameLayout
>             xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             android:id="@+id/fragment_container_rigth"
>          .../>
>     />
```

and each fragment  are load  with the following code :

```
> <ListView
>     android:id="@+id/listView1" 
>  ... />
```

and my testing is the following :

```
@Override
protected void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mActivity = getActivity();
    mIns = this.getInstrumentation();
    solo = new Solo(mIns, mActivity);
}
public void testBackButton() {

      // click in listView
      solo.clickInList(0);
      solo.clickInList(0);               
 ... }
```

the problem is that solo.clickInList(0), always being done click the ListView element belonging to the fragment  on the right laden.
how do to "solo.clickInList()"  click the list on the left [here image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMOPn.png) ??

Comment: SORY : always being done click the ListView element belonging to the fragment on the left laden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `solo.clickInList(0, integer);` that lets you specify which list to click. Did you try that? You can also click on a specific text.

Comment: thank dmon - this is the solution `solo.clickInList(0,2);` never tried with it.